# Eclipse CDT debugging fails when writing to stdout just before function ending

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, debugging, stdout

I've encountered something that I can't explain while working with Eclipse today.

Basically, when I try to debug a function that writes to stdout just before ending, Eclipse will not return from the function and will stop debugging there.  (The function may do other things as long as it writes to stdout last.)

A program that causes the unexpected behaviour would be, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testfunc(void)
{
    puts("I hate you ");

}

int main(void)
{
    testfunc();

    printf("so, so much.");
    return 3;
}
```

In this case, it also shows some strange memory locations in the stack trace.

printf causes the same behaviour as well. It's remarkable to mention that this doesn't happen when I step over the function, only when I trace into it, which would appear to point to a problem that is not from the code I showed.

Changing the function to:

```
void testfunc(void)
{
    int a;
    a=3;
    puts("I hate you ");

}
```

Gets a SIGSEGV signal sent to the process, while:

```
void testfunc(void)
{
    int a;

    puts("I hate you ");
    a=3;
}
```

Works without problems.

As I said, stepping over the function or just running the program (not debugging) works fine, as does compiling manually with gcc and running the program on a terminal.

I'm running Fedora 19, and Eclipse is Version: 4.3.1, Build id: 5fc19

Any ideas?